# Adding UV image to an object

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, uv-image-editor, texture-coordinates, seams

I've created a punching bag and the goal is to place a bullseye on it with the current texture. When I create the seams and unwrap, multiple bullseye appear and I only need 1.
Do I have to bake the image into the punching bag? Thanks

File: https://we.tl/t-AtoJ0N64Wp

Goal:
[image]

Currently:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can see in the *UV Editor* or in the *Image Editor*:

[image]

But if you enable the *View > Repeat Image* option you'll see how the image will actually be projected onto the surface of your object:

[image]

To avoid that you can choose the *Clip* or *Extend* option, instead of *Repeat*, in the *Image Texture*:

[image]

Note that you may prefer to have transparency beside your circle logo, instead of grey. To do that you need to use a b&w image or an image with transparency as a factor in a *Mix Shader*.

Comment: Excellent answer! How can I add color/texture to the punching bag if my bullseye png is plugged into the base color? Like the 'goal' picture I added? Thank you!

Comment: If you want to do exactly like the image you show, you need to have your red sign on an image with a transparent background, another image with the background texture, mix the 2 images texture nodes into a Color > Mix Color node, plug the Alpha output of the sign image into the factor input of the Mix Color node

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!